# How to use telegraf webhook?

Tags: node.js, telegraf.js

I want to use webHook in telegraf but i don't know how can i use it correctly.

Here is my simple code.
But it still uses polling.

```
    const Telegraf = require('telegraf');
    const bot = new Telegraf('123:ABC');

    bot.telegram.setWebhook('https://myaddress.com');
    bot.startWebhook(`/`, null, 4000);



    bot.use(function(ctx, next){
        try{
            if(ctx.chat == undefined) return;
            console.log("Hello World");
        }catch (e){
            console.log("Error");
        }
    });


    bot.launch();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When `bot.startWebhook()` is called Telegraf [will start listening to the provided webhook url](https://v3.telegrafjs.org/#/telegraf?id=startwebhook), so you don't need to call `bot.launch()` after that.

Also `bot.launch()` [will start the bot in polling mode by default](https://v3.telegrafjs.org/#/telegraf?id=launch) if no options are specified as in your case.

Remove `bot.launch()` and the bot should start in webhook mode.

### Telegraf.js ^4.0.0

If you're using Telegraf.js version 4.0 or higher the [changelog](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/releases/tag/v4.0.0) states that:

> Bots should now always be started using bot.launch with the corresponding configuration for either long polling (default) or webhooks.

So you can also try removing `bot.telegram.setWebhook()` and `bot.startWebhook()`, adding the following code instead:

```
bot.launch({
  webhook: {
    domain: 'https://myaddress.com',
    port: 4000
  }
})
```

See [this example](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/blob/develop/docs/examples/webhook-bot.js)  from the documentation for reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
  bot.startWebhook('/messages', null, 8443);
  bot.launch();
```

Second parameter are tlsOptions, it's optional.
I have read that Telegram only accepts webhooks on 80, 88, 443 and 8443.
Not sure if true, but is something important to consider since it's very difficult to troubleshoot webhooks.